# Change in Matrix (m x n) in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an m x n Matrix, which I call data.
The last column consist of values between 1 and 7.
I want to find the value 7 in that column , and change the values of the other column which are in the same row as the value 7.

How can i do this?

Comment: Ex:    Data is  [ 1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 5; 4 2 3 4;7 1 7 5] and the result is   [ 1 2 3 4; -1 2 -3  5; -4  2 -3 4;7 1 7 5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative version of Oli Charlesworth's answer without `find`:

```
n=6;
% Build random matrix
data=[rand(7,n) (1:7)'];
% Replace row with last column at 7 with vector (1:7)
data(data(:,end)==7,:)=(1:7);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
idx_row = find(data(:,end) == 7);
data(idx_row,:) == data(idx_row,end);
```

Comment: This give me à new sett of Matrix, how can i put it back in its old place??